# method with angle brackets (<>)

Tags: scala, syntax, dsl, syntactic-sugar

Is it possible to have angle brackets in method names , e.g. :

```
class Foo(ind1:Int,ind2:Int){...}
var v = new Foo(1,2)
v(1) = 3 //updates ind1
v<1> = 4 //updates ind2
```

The real situation is obviously more complicated than this!!I am trying to provide a convenient user interface.

Comment: You mean angle bracket in method calls, not in method names?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This response is not meant to be taken too seriously - just a proof that this can almost be achieved using some hacks.

```
class Vector(values: Int*) {
  val data = values.toArray
  def < (i:Int) = new {
    def `>_=`(x: Int) {
      data(i) = x
    }
    def > {
      println("value at "+ i +" is "+ data(i))
    }
  }
  override def toString = data.mkString("<", ", ", ">")
}

val v = new Vector(1, 2, 3)
println(v) // prints <1, 2, 3>
v<1> = 10
println(v) // prints <1, 10, 3>
v<1> // prints: value at 1 is 10
```

Using this class we can have a vector that uses `<>` instead of `()` for "read" and write access.
The compiler (2.9.0.1) crashes if `>` returns a value. It might be a bug or a result of misusing `>`.

Comment: Very nice. I had tried to define ``>_=`` but didn't try with the backticks. Cool!

Comment: If the compiler actually crashes (prints a stack trace and exits), it's a bug.  Please report it if that's the case.

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup: I just filed a bug for the issue.

Comment: `>_=` so looks like a moe face, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** I was wrong; kassens's answer shows how to do it as you want.

---

It is not possible to implement a method that would be called when you write `v<1> = 4` (except, maybe, if you write a compiler plugin?). However, something like this would be possible:

```
class Foo {
  def at(i: Int) = new Assigner(i)
  class Assigner(i: Int) {
    def :=(v: Int) = println("assigning " + v + " at index " + i)
  }
}
```

Then:

```
val f = new Foo
f at 4 := 6
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little trickery you can actually get quite close to what you want.

```
object Foo {
  val a:Array[Int] = new Array(100)
  def <(i:Int) = new Updater(a, i)
}

class Updater(a:Array[Int], i:Int) {
  def update(x:Int) {
    a(i) = x
  }
  def >() = this
}

Foo<1>() = 123
```

I am not sure why Scala requires the `()` though. And yes, this is a bit of a hack...