# Need clarification on Scala literal identifiers (backticks)

Tags: scala

Reading the Programming in Scala 2nd Ed and I came across this:

literal identifier
"The idea is that you can put any string that's accepted by the runtime as an identifier between backtick"

I'm not entirely sure why I would use this? The book gave a use case of accessing the static yield method in Java's Thread class.

So since in Scala, yield is a reserve word, if I use yield with backticks,

```
Thread.`yield`()
```

it would ignore the Scala's yield and let me access the Java's Thread class's method yield instead?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Exactly. Using backticks, you can more or less give any name to a field identifier. In fact, you can even say

```
val ` ` = 0
```

which defines a variable with name (one character of whitespace).

The literal definition of identifiers is useful in two cases. The first case is, when there is already a reserved word of the same name in Scala and you need to use a Java library which does not care about that (and of course, why should it).

The other use case comes with `case` statements. The convention is that lower case names refer to match variables, whereas upper case names refer to identifiers from the outer scope. So,

```
val A = "a"
val b = "b"
"a" match {
  case b => println("b")
  case A => println("A")
}
```

prints `"b"` (if the compiler were dumb enough not to fail with saying `case A` were unreachable). If you want to refer to the originally defined `val b`, you need to use backticks as a marker.

```
"a" match {
  case `b` => println("b")
  case A => println("A")
}
```

Which prints `"A"`.

**Add** There is a more advanced use case in this recent question [method with angle brackets (<>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571810/method-with-angle-brackets/6572945#6572945) where the backticks were needed to get the compiler to digesting the code for a setter method (which in itself uses some ‘magic’ syntax).

Comment: There also seems to be a special case for package objects. E.g. in `Predef.scala`, there is this line: ``scala.`package` // to force scala package object to be seen.`` Not sure it's a special case though… Any comment?

Comment: Normally, you would not need to refer to a specific package object but just import whatever method you need from the package. In the Predef, I guess, this is a bit special because you explicitly want to expose those methods. Apart from that, it is not really special. It turns a keyword into an identifier just the same.

Comment: Ok, maybe it’s not exposing but something else.

Comment: You can also define a package object with: `object \`package\` {}`

Comment: It also allows one to have a script called `my-script.scala` with `object \`my-script\``.

Comment: Another case where literal identifiers can be very useful: producing JSON with a Scala reserved word as field name (e.g. `{"type": "foo"}`) using Play's JSON API. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34018822/56285

Answer (score 20):

Thank you @Debilski, it helps me to understand this code below from AKKA doc :

```
class WatchActor extends Actor {
    val child = context.actorOf(Props.empty, "child")
    ...
    def receive = {
        ...
        case Terminated(`child`) ⇒ ...
    }
}
```

The case :

```
case Terminated(`child`)
```

matches a message of type Terminated with ActorRef field equals to child which is defined earlier.

With this statement :

```
case Terminated(c)
```

We match every Terminated messages with any reference of ActorRef mapped in **c**.

Comment: +1 Happens to be the precise situation I was looking for when i googled!

Comment: what type and value is c?

Comment: an ActorRef but not especially the child instance