# Why the need for separate Swing API in Scala

Tags: swing, scala

Scala comes in-built with a separate [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/package.html) for Swing. Why did the language designers come up with a decision to have this?

Java's swing package can be used as any other java library to build GUI applications in Scala. Then what was the need to have a new wrapper over this when the existing one is already well prevalent.

PS: Concrete answers please! We all know the general advantages of Scala.

Comment: Because we can? Scala version is glorified and allows you to write concise code (the situation is like with java/scala api for Akka). If you can remove clutter, why won't you do it?

Comment: But is it worth so much complexity for such vast the library and functionality is?

Comment: @Jatin no it's not, it's a wrapper and it's not very well maintained (dead?) . But swing itself is not very well maintained so...

Answer (score 2):

This goes to the "general advantages of Scala," but Scala reduces the pain point of wiring up listeners, which is the bulk of assembly in Swing.

Sample recent question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199439/listeners-and-reactions-in-scala-swing/). You can go the next mile with scala.react.