# Scala.swing How does one scala components to current window size

Tags: swing, scala

I'm trying to display an image in a SimpleSwingApplication. I would like to make the image change size when the window changes size (i.e. manually dragging the cursor to adjust size).

I think this is done by listening for something, then reacting with UIElementResized.

But I'm not sure how to actually do it.

I've tried:

```
        listenTo(top) \\ or Window/Frame/UIEvent
        reactions += {
            // case UIElementResized=>
            case class UIElementResized(source: UIElement); => // or without the semicolon, without "source: UIElement", without "class", and a few other permutations.
               println(size) 
        }
```

I asked a similar question yesterday, but it was narrow. I want to make a more broad question about the entire problem.

Comment: well, you definitely want to do `case UIElementResized(source) =>` this is your valid permutation. `case UIElementResized(source: UIElement) =>`  is fine as well. I am only adressing pattern matching thing, I don't know about swing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Swing, but it looks like reactions use partial functions as callbacks. So the issue is in your pattern matching syntax, try

```
reactions += {
    case UIElementResized(source) => println(source.size)
}
```

You can find more detailed examples here:
[Listeners and reactions in Scala Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199439/listeners-and-reactions-in-scala-swing)