# Scala match variable passing

Tags: scala, match

I am new to Scala, and was trying to understand match.

When I try to run the following code, the javaw VM does not respond (keeps waiting for ever - trying this from eclipse)

```
case GenericProfile(user) => processGenericProfile(_)
case _ => println("Invalid data found")
```

However, the following section works just fine:

```
case GenericProfile(user) => processGenericProfile(GenericProfile(user))
case _ => println("Invalid data found")
```

I am trying to understand why the first scenario would fail to respond. I do not want to pass GenericProfile(user) - I would like to know how this can be simplified. Thnaks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

without seeing how `processGenericProfile` and `GenericProfile` are defined it's hard to tell for sure, but I think your first case (`case GenericProfile(user) => processGenericProfile(_)`) is just returning a partially applied function `processGenericProfile` and not applying it to the results on the left hand of the case as I understand you want to do...

Consider this REPL sessions, where I give "fake" definitions for `processGenericProfile` and `GenericProfile`

```
scala> case class GenericProfile(user: String)
defined class GenericProfile

scala> def processGenericProfile(u: GenericProfile) = "processed"
processGenericProfile: (u: GenericProfile)java.lang.String

scala> GenericProfile("Paolo") match {
     | case GenericProfile(user) => processGenericProfile(_)
     | case _ => "wrong"
     | }
res0: java.lang.Object = <function1>
```

See the return type of the `match`? It's likely that you are not stuck, the match returns a function and does not apply it, so you're waiting for something to happen, but scala thinks it has already done what you wanted to do (return a function).

If you need to capture the whole `GenericProfile`, instead of just the user it contains, you can [use an alias](https://coderwall.com/p/m1bnlq) with the `@` symbol, like this:

```
    scala> GenericProfile("Paolo") match {
         | case u @ GenericProfile(user) => processGenericProfile(u)
         | case _ => "wrong"
         | }
    res2: java.lang.String = processed
```

One last thing. I'm not sure what the "user" in `case GenericProfile(user)` represents. The way I wrote it, it's a name that is bound to the value contained in the `GenericProfile`. I.e. in the first case we're saying "if the item we're checking is a `GenericProfile`, take the string it contains ("Paolo" in this case) and bind it to a name `user`.

Since you are not using that value on the right-hand side, you can also do:

```
case u @ GenericProfile(_) => processGenericProfile(u)
```

where the `_` on the left hand side makes it explicit that you're discarding the matched user and you're just interested in checking that the type is a `GenericProfile`.

If instead "user" is a variable that you defined previously (i.e. you want your case statement to check that you have a `GenericProfile` for a specific user), then you need to tell scala that `user` is something you defined and not a name you want to bind to whatever is found in `GenericProfile`. That can be done by [surrounding your identifier (user) with backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks), like this:

```
val user="Paolo"

GenericProfile("Paolo") match {
    case u @ GenericProfile(`user`) => processGenericProfile(u) 
                                               //now this only matches                      
                                               //GenericProfile("Paolo")
    case GenericProfile(_) => "not Paolo"    
    case _ => "wrong"
}
```

Comment: You were right - I was unknowingly using a partial function. Thanks for the detailed response - Inspiring!!