# Is there a Groovy equivalent to Scala's literal identifiers?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Scala's literal identifiers are described in [Need clarification on Scala literal identifiers (backticks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks).

Background: I'm converting an Ant build system to Gradle. We currently have a file `dependencies.properties` with definitions like:

```
com.netflix.archaius.archaius-core.rev=latest.release
```

But Groovy doesn't like the `.` and `-` in the property names (since they're operators). Rather than changing the names of the properties and everything using them, is there a way to tell Groovy to consider the `.` and `-` as simply another character in the property name?

Comment: Could [this doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) and [this discussion](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Load-properties-from-an-arbitrary-properties-file-td3408710.html) help? You can very well use GString implementations where you see `-`. For eg: `com.netflix.archaius.'archaius-core'.rev=${latest.release}`

Comment: Why aren't you just parsing the properties file as a properties file, and, if necessary, do some simple string replacement on the resulting map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does not provide literal identifiers, as in Scala, but it should solve your root problem. Given this dependencies.properties file:

```
foo=bar
com.netflix.archaius.archaius-core.rev=latest.release
```

and then this Gradle script:

```
ant.property(file: "dependencies.properties")

task go() {
    println ant."com.netflix.archaius.archaius-core.rev"
    println ant.foo
    println "done."
}
```

the output is (edited for brevity):

```
bash-3.2$ gradle go
latest.release
bar
done.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.26 secs
```

Comment: In our build, the properties get put in the `project` scope so either `project.'com.netflix.archaius.archaius-core.rev'` or `project[''com.netflix.archaius.archaius-core.rev']` works.