# Scala reserved word as JSON field name with Json.writes[A] (Play equivalent for @SerializedName)

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm producing JSON with Play 2.4.3 & Scala in the following fashion, providing an implicit `Writes[DeviceJson]` created with `Json.writes`.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class DeviceJson(name: String, serial: Long, type: String)

object DeviceJson {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[DeviceJson]
}
```

Of course, the above doesn't compile as I'm trying ot use the reserved word `type` as field name in the case class.

In this scenario, what is the *simplest* way to output JSON field names such as `type` or `match` that I can't use as Scala field names?

With Java and Gson, for example, using a custom JSON field name (different from the field name in code) would be trivial with [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation. Similarly in Jackson with `@JsonProperty`.

I know I can do this by rolling my own `Writes` implementation:

```
case class DeviceJson(name: String, serial: Long, deviceType: String)

object DeviceJson {
  implicit val writes = new Writes[DeviceJson] {
    def writes(json: DeviceJson) = {
      Json.obj(
        "name" -> json.name,
        "serial" -> json.serial,
        "type" -> json.deviceType
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But this is clumsy and repetitive, especially if the class has a lot of fields. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your case class, you can use backtick for field name:

```
case class DeviceJson(name: String, serial: Long, `type`: String)
```

With this, your `Writes` should work

Comment: Nice, thank you! I had to look it up; names like these are called [literal identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks).

Comment: With a custom Jackson `ObjectMapper` in Play framework this does not seem to work. Any suggestions, is there some config value I have to supply to the ObjectMapper?