# Does TypeScript has variable names escaping feature like backticks in Scala for literal identifiers?

Tags: scala, typescript, naming

Does TypeScript has variable names escaping feature like backticks in Scala for literal identifiers:

```
`0029-otherwise-illegal-scala-literal`
```

See Scala explanation in [Need clarification on Scala literal identifiers (backticks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks)

Comment: No (that I'm aware of). Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been really easy to test this for yourself though? But, @NitzanTomer is correct on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the spec at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.2

Section 2.2.2 tells you

> The PropertyName production from the ECMAScript grammar is reproduced
>   below:
>
> PropertyName:    LiteralPropertyName    ComputedPropertyName
>
> LiteralPropertyName:    IdentifierName    StringLiteral
>      NumericLiteral
>
> ComputedPropertyName:    [ AssignmentExpression ]
>
> A property name can be any identifier (including a reserved word), a
>   string literal, a numeric literal, or a computed property name. String
>   literals may be used to give properties names that are not valid
>   identifiers, such as names containing blanks. Numeric literal property
>   names are equivalent to string literal property names with the string
>   representation of the numeric literal, as defined in the ECMAScript
>   specification.

This includes string literals.

You can declare a property as a string literal:

```
class MyClass {
  "return" = 1;
}
```

you can access it with square brackets

```
let myinstance = new MyClass()
let one = myinstance["return"]
```

Comment: That's not quite the same. He asked for a variable name, and what you provided is for property name, which is a more specific case. Maybe that's what he meant, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @NitzanTomer indeed, I have asked for the variable naming.

Comment: It didn't properly answered my question, but as @NitzanTomer noted, there's no such feature.