# How can I automatically map JSON to a case class when a field is a scala keyword?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

Within the *Play Framework (2.6)*; I am currently [automatically mapping](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) JSON to case classes from MongoDB (using *ReactiveMongo 0.12* with *JSON Collections*). I have downloaded a dataset ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/neighborhoods.json)) and imported it into *MongoDB* as a *collection* in order to do some testing relating to **geospatial queries**. However one of the fields is called "*type*" (at a quick glance you will see this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/#exploring-the-data)) so I am having issues as this is a keyword in *Scala*. This would otherwise be what I would write:

```
   case class Geometry(coordinates: List, type: String)
   case class Neighborhood(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], geometry: Geometry, name: String)
```

### Many thanks for any suggestions here!

Just to add (thanks to @MarioGalic); declaring *scala keywords* as class parameter names seems to be done with backticks but I am still having an issue outputting these in the *Play templates*. So if I was looping through each document I might write this (which is getting an error).

```
   @for(ngh <- neighborhoods){
     <tr>
        ...
        <td>@ngh.name</td>
        <td>@ngh.geometry.`type`</td>
        ...
     </tr>
   }
```

Without backticks doesn't work here and with backticks aren't recognised within the *template*. I cannot find any other formats in [this referenced question/answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks) so I am still having an issue. Thanks

---

Sorry this is obvious as to what to do. Within the *case class model* just define a method that has a different name (from "type" in this example but essentially any *keyword* which is causing an issue:

```
   case class Geometry(coordinates: List, `type`: String) {
      def getType = `type`
   }
```

Then call this in the *template*:

```
   @for(ngh <- neighborhoods){
     <tr>
        ...
        <td>@ngh.name</td>
        <td>@ngh.geometry.getType</td>
        ...
     </tr>
   }
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the field `type` with [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) like so:

```
case class Geometry(coordinates: List, `type`: String)
```

The following answer explains backticks syntax in more detail:
[Need clarification on Scala literal identifiers (backticks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576594/need-clarification-on-scala-literal-identifiers-backticks)

Comment: This makes sense. The only thing is that they don't help when pulling the information into a template - please see my edited question above. And thanks again!

Comment: Solved this issue just mentioned as edited in the question. Your answer was the catalyst for this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your code in **curly braces** like this:

```
@{ngh.geometry.`type`}
```

and the `type` field will be properly rendered in the Play template. There is no need to create the `getType` method.

Your full working code would be:

```
@for(ngh <- neighborhoods){
   <tr>
     ...
     <td>@ngh.name</td>
     <td>@{ngh.geometry.`type`}</td>
     ...
   </tr>
}
```