# Call a method named `var` in Scala

Tags: scala, reserved-words, scala-java-interop, backticks

I am using a third-part Java library, which defines a method named `var`.  In Java, that is not a problem.  In Scala, `var`is a reserved word and `obj.var()` gives a compilation error.

Is there a more elegant solution to this than `obj.getClass().getMethod("var").invoke()`?

Comment: how about `\`var\`` with backticks?

Comment: [Scala literal identifiers (backticks)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6576594/432903)

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks!