# Scala: How to use a `MatchesRegex` refinement with a regex containing a backtick (refined library)?

Tags: scala

The [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) library allows to define refinement that matches a given `regex`, as shown in the `Readme`:

```
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.string._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined

type MyType = String Refined MatchesRegex[W.`"[0-9]+"`.T]
```

While this works perfectly fine, we can't define this way a type that matches a regex containing a backtick, because as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545195/5826349) there is no way to escape a backtick within a `literal`:

```
 type MyType = String Refined MatchesRegex[W.`"(a|`)"`.T]

 // Getting a compile-error:
 // ']' expected but ')' found.
```

So would there be a way to define such a type (i.e `MatchesRegex` with a regex containing a backtick)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do so is to use [singleton types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) available in Scala 2.13 or [Typelevel Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/typelevel-4.md).

For Typelevel Scala, you need to add / replace in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaOrganization := "org.typelevel",
scalaVersion := "2.12.4-bin-typelevel-4", // Assuming you are using scala 2.12
```

And you need to add the compiler flag `-Yliteral-types`:

```scala
scalacOptions := Seq(
                  ..., // Other options
                  "-Yliteral-types"
                 )
```

And now the `refined` type can simply be:

```scala
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined

type MyType = String Refined MatchesRegex["""(a|`)"""]
```